# How to stop closing whole application while closing xcool window form

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a Project like CMS, I am working on it and I have add a theme xcool.

There are 50 Window Form here but now problem is that while closing one Window form, the Whole application is closing.

When I remove this theme its working good. I did not find any closing Method of Theme, etc.

What I have tried:

```
using System.IO;

namespace CampusManagement
{
    public partial class Student_Reg : XCoolForm.XCoolForm

    private XmlThemeLoader xtl = new XmlThemeLoader();


    this.TitleBar.TitleBarBackImage = CampusManagement.Properties.Resources.predator_256x256;
    this.MenuIcon = CampusManagement.Properties.Resources.alien_vs_predator_3_48x48.GetThumbnailImage(24, 24, null, IntPtr.Zero);
    xtl.ThemeForm = this;
    this.Border.BorderStyle = XCoolForm.X3DBorderPrimitive.XBorderStyle.Flat;
    this.TitleBar.TitleBarBackImage = CampusManagement.Properties.Resources.Mammooth_1;
    this.TitleBar.TitleBarCaption = "Campus Management System";
    xtl.ApplyTheme(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\..\Themes\BlueWinterTheme.xml"));
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33716/WebControls/?fid=1536616&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=71&prof=True#usingcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways you can fix this.

1. If you look at the source for XCoolForm, in `XCoolForm.cs` under the `OnMouseDown` event handler.  There are two places where it checks if the button clicked was the close button (line 312 and line 353).  If the close button was clicked it exits the application.

   ```
   else if (xbtn.XButtonType == XTitleBarButton.XTitleBarButtonType.Close)
   {
       Application.Exit();
   }
   ```

   You want to change `Application.Exit()` to `Close()` instead.

   ```
   else if (xbtn.XButtonType == XTitleBarButton.XTitleBarButtonType.Close)
   {
       Close();
   }
   ```
2. Another option is to override the OnMouseDown event.  But you need to make `m_xTitleBar` and `PointInRect` protected so that you can access them.  In `XCoolForm.cs` change `m_xTitleBar` from private to protected on line 63:

   ```
   protected XTitleBar m_xTitleBar = new XTitleBar();
   ```

   And change the `PointInRect` function from private to protected on line 935:

   ```
   protected bool PointInRect(Point p, Rectangle rc)
   ```

   Then in your form you can override the mouse down event like this:

   ```
   protected override void OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (XTitleBarButton xbtn in m_xTitleBar.TitleBarButtons)
       {
           if (PointInRect(
               e.Location,
               new Rectangle(
                   xbtn.XButtonLeft,
                   xbtn.XButtonTop,
                   xbtn.XButtonWidth,
                   xbtn.XButtonHeight
               )))
           {
                 // We just want to check if it was the close button that was clicked, if so then we close this form.
                 if (xbtn.XButtonType == XTitleBarButton.XTitleBarButtonType.Close)
                 {
                     Close();
                     return;
                 }
           }
       }

       // It wasn't the close button that was clicked, so run the base handler and let it take care of the button click.   
       base.OnMouseDown(e);
   }
   ```

Comment: But you need to make m_xTitleBar and PointInRect protected so you can access them. Please Help me how i can access.... it is procted

Comment: Please Help me i am Using Themes from Here...  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33716/WebControls/?fid=1536616&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=71&prof=True#usingcode

Comment: @KhuramShahzad I add more details about the second method.  Please let me know where you're stuck.

Comment: i did not find any code which you mention in second Method .... and other issue arise now ..... r,g,b color issue